# Program to remove all occurrences of a word in given string

Tags: c, string

I have written the code but the output is not coming correct: if I input `How you doing` as an original string and then want to remove `you`, the output should be `How doing`, but instead the output is coming as `How you doing` (same as the input string).

Here is my code:

```
void removeWord(char *,char *);

int main() {
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter any string: ");
    gets(str);

    char re[20];
    printf("\nEnter word to remove: ");
    gets(re);

    printf("\nString befor removing '%s' : \n%s", re, str);

    removeWord(str, re);

    printf("\nString after removing '%s' : \n%s", re, str);

    return 0;
}

void removeWord(char *str, char *re) {
    int slen, rlen, found, j;

    slen = strlen(str);
    rlen = strlen(re);

    for (int i = 0; i <= slen - rlen; i++) {
        found = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < rlen; j++) {
            if (str[i + j] != re[i + j]) {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (str[i + j] != ' ' && str[i + j] != '\t' && str[i + j] != '\n' && str[i + j] !='\0')
            found = 0;

        if (found == 1) {
            for (int k = i; k <= slen - rlen; k++)
                str[k] = str[k + rlen];

            slen -= rlen;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: basic?!? Please read the tag descriptions before using them. This is not BASIC, and it is either C or C++, but not both

Comment: Here string is 'str' is the original string from which we want to remove the word "re".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the best way to remove substring from a given string.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
  using namespace std;
  int main()  
  {
  string str="My name is ankit mishra";
  string sub="name is";
  size_t found = str.find(sub);
  int len=sub.length();
  int l=str.length();
  int len_diff=l-found+1-len;
  int tag;
  cout<<"Original String: "<<str<<endl;
  cout<<"Sub-String: "<<sub<<endl;
  int i=found;
  while(len_diff--)
  {
    str[i]=str[i+len];
    i++;
  }

  string newstr;
  for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
  newstr+=str[j];
  cout<<"New String :" <<newstr;

  }
```

[Check Output of this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KVs2.png)

Answer (score 2):

you can use predefined function to get first index of substring. In C we have function 'strstr()'
. If sub-string is present in string it will return first index of that sub-string otherwise if not present it will return highest value possible in that data data type.

In cpp we have 'size_t found = str.find(substr); '  check this article on GFG [string find in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-find-in-cpp/)

Comment: I think if I code in cpp then this function will make the program way simple but in c this function only returns the address of first such word. it can not even return the address of second word. As far as I know. If I am wrong, feel free to comment.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an update to your code that does it:

You had some code to catch a corner case that was giving it a lot of problems.  I commented it out as I didn't understand the purpose.  Take a look at it if I missed why its important.  I also corrected a few indexing bugs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeWord(char *,char *);

int main()
{
    char str[100] = {0};  //Initialize fully
    char re[20] = {0};

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    gets(str);

    printf("\nEnter word to remove: ");
    gets(re);

    printf("\nString before removing '%s' : %s",re,str);

    removeWord(str,re);

    printf("\nSrting after removing '%s' : %s",re,str);

    return 0;
}

void removeWord(char *str,char *re)
{
    int slen,rlen,found,j,k;

    slen = strlen(str);
    rlen = strlen(re);

    for(int i=0; i<=slen-rlen; i++)
    {
        found = 1;
        for(j=0; j<rlen; j++)
        {
            if(str[i+j] != re[j])
            {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == 1)
        {
            for(k=i;k<rlen;k++)
            {
                str[k] = str[k + rlen];
            }
            str[k] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Oh got it.<br/> Thanks Man.<br/> BTW we have to include <pre>if (str[i + j] != ' ' && str[i + j] != '\t' && str[i + j] != '\n' && str[i + j] !='\0')
            found = 0;<code><br/>Cause if want to remove "you" and we have the word word "your" in the sentence this program will also remove "you" from "your".<br/>still big help man

Comment: Ahh, understood! You should have no problem throwing that fix right back in there.  If this resolves it please feel free to mark it as such.

Comment: and seriously I am still not getting how to use linebreaks.